# Can the following python code be changed to one line? #python

Tags: python

```
str2 = "15X8XXX6X8X"
for i in range(len(str2)):
    if str2[i] == "X":
        str2 = str2.replace("X", str2[i-1], 1)
print(str2)
```

Output result: 15588886688

Fill X with the previous value. How can the above code be simplified? If it is convenient, other ideas are better, and write them in one line as much as possible. Many Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Your title and question text are two different, often unrelated questions. "changed to one line" is *not* the same as "simplified" and is very often the opposite of simpler.

Comment: Yes.  However, execution speed does not depend on number of lines, and debugging difficulty is greatly increased.   Other than code golf, there's no real reason to insist on fewest lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```py
import functools

str2 = "15X8XXX6X8X"
print(''.join(functools.reduce(lambda s, c: s + (s[-1] if c == 'X' else c), str2)))
# Outputs 15588886688
```

This basically reads "for each character in `str2`, build a string with the last character read if the current character is `'X'` else with the current character".

---

An alternative is using [`itertools.accumulate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.accumulate):

```
import itertools

str2 = "15X8XXX6X8X"
print(''.join(itertools.accumulate(str2, lambda s, c: c.replace('X', s[-1]))))
# Outputs 15588886688
```

This improves readability a little bit, but less code is not synonym of good code.

Comment: This does answer the OP question, however, this type of code makes debugging super hard.

Comment: @CodeLikeBeaker I'm just for learning, thank you for your suggestions.